# How to create and style dropdown menus using the wordpress menus section?

Tags: php, html, css, wordpress, drop-down-menu

relatively new to coding here.

I followed a tutorial that showed me how to set my website's navigation menu to display links that are configured within the menus section in the wordpress dashboard. I followed the next tutorial hoping to find out how to make dropdown menus for child/sub pages, but it only showed how to do this by entering all the hyperlinks manually in the html. I really don't want to do it this way as it defeats the object of the first tutorial and makes it less easy from a CMS / client usability perspective, could somebody help me out? I think it has something to do with the php code I entered into my functions folder, but I'm not sure.

website - www.lucieaverill.co.uk

HTML

```
`<nav class="site-nav">
<?php $args = array('theme_location' => 'primary'); ?>
<?php wp_nav_menu(); ?>
</nav>`
```

CSS

```
`.header nav ul{
display:block;
float:right;
width:auto;
margin-top:15px;
padding: 0;
background-color:#ffffff;
list-style:none; }

.header nav ul li {
float:left;
padding-left:50px; }
```

PHP

```
`register_nav_menus(array( 'header' => 
__( 'Header Menu' ),
));`
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need to ensure you're passing those $args to the wp_nav_menu() function as such "wp_nav_menu($args)".

Second, you have just about everything you need and might not realize it. =)  Inside of the WordPress menu editor (after logging in and navigating to Appearance -> Menus, you simply need to drag/drop a link below another so that it becomes a child.  You will see it pop over to the right.. that means it is now in it's own sub menu.  These menus can be nested and nested.

The rest is simply CSS.  You will just need to set the '.header nav ul ul' to 'display: none;' to hide them and display them again when hovered as '.header ul li:hover ul' with 'display: block;'.

You shouldn't have to code any more PHP or HTML than you already have.  WordPress will automatically add in the HTML.

Comment: Thanks so much, you're a lifesaver - it worked! 

A couple of things have caught my eye since doing this. Currently I've laid out my main header menu with all the links floated to the right of the page with 50px of padding to the left of each of them to create space in between. I want to switch the padding to the right (to make the dropdown menu smoother) and disable the padding for the last link - do you know how I could achieve this? I read somewhere that you can do it by selecting the "last child", but all the ways in which I have tried this have failed.

Comment: Secondly, part of the css I've written makes any menu link that has been clicked stay highlighted purple while the viewer is on that page. This was intentional, however now that I have child pages in the dropdown menu, they all stay that color too. Is there a way of fixing this? it would be ideal if both the parent link and the specific child link stayed highlighted purple whilst the viewer was on a that particular child page.

Comment: @Jack1991 - For your first request, selected the last child will work just fine.  This site here will show you which browsers it works with: caniuse(dot)com. The way you will want to use this is on your list elements rather than the anchors inside each link item. So, for instance ".header ul li:last-child { padding-right: 0; }". This will likely make the anchors inside each list element, however, not as large as you want to solve this, apply 'position: relative' to your LI elements and then apply a 'position: absolute' to your anchors inside along with 'top: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0;'.

Comment: @Jack1991 - For the second request, I would need to see your code structure and CSS in order to help.  It sounds like you just have a style applied to a list element and it's applying to all children.  You would just need to figure out the logic in order to reverse this behavior for the children.  If you send me a quick jsfiddle link with the HTML/CSS used, I can be of more assistance!